# API returns Forbidden when creating an online meeting endpoint

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to [create an online meeting endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

The token has the correct scopes (`"scp": "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite openid TeamsApp.ReadWrite profile email"`) but when I call `POST /v1.0/me/onlineMeetings` with the following body

```json
{
  "startDateTime":"2019-07-12T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2019-07-12T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
  "subject":"User Token Meeting"
}
```

I get:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-01-06T13:35:38",
            "request-id": "cc25adbc-2e37-4626-8c14-4f90038056cd",
            "client-request-id": "cc25adbc-2e37-4626-8c14-4f90038056cd"
        }
    }
}
```

I also get a forbidden response when using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Comment: Does the authenticated user have permission to create a meeting via the Teams UI?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Yes, I'm not sure in what tenant it does it tho.

Comment: Graph only speaks to one tenant at a time (which ever tenant you authenticated against).

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Thanks, how can I change the tenant? it's automatically connected to the main/home tenant?

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: Please see my answer update, is it helpful to you?

Comment: @CarlZhao I think I understand the problem, My authorization URL was for a specific tenant instead of  `organizations`, I didn't update because I'm waiting for getting consent from my admin to make sure things are working before answer and close this ticket. thanks!

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: @CarlZhao not yet

Comment: @CarlZhao yeah.. the problem solved. thanks!

Comment: @Michael  I'm so happy for you, can you share your solution and mark it, it may be helpful to other members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I authorized the user against specific tenant:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/550fae72-d251-43ec-868c-373732c2704f/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

Instead of:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

Answer (score 1):

The api call only supports work or school account login, does not support Microsoft personal accounts, nor does it support guest accounts. check!

[image]

[image]

---

**Update:**

1. Make sure you are logged in to a work account (It is an AAD account, not a B2C account). If you call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`, you will find that the ID of your work account is like this, **"id": "987932c9-f062-48e2- 8ced-22cb6896dfce"** and the ID of the Microsoft account is like this **"id": "5d9ee9b4b2ad3bfe"**.
2. Parse your access token and make sure that the `acct` claim is `0`.
3. Try to add the **organizer** in the **request body**:

```
{
      "startDateTime":"2019-09-09T14:33:30.8546353-07:00",
      "endDateTime":"2019-09-09T15:03:30.8566356-07:00",
      "subject":"Application Token Meeting",
      "participants": {
        "organizer": {
          "identity": {
            "user": {
              "id": "550fae72-d251-43ec-868c-373732c2704f"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: @Michael  Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.